# Java get java.awt.Color from string

Tags: java, formatting, awt

So I have a string that looks something like this:
`text java.awt.Color[r=128,g=128,b=128]text 1234`

How could I pop out the color and get the rgb values?

Comment: You need to parse the text. What have you tried? (Can you post)

Comment: I havent tried anything yet... im asking because I dont know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the rgb values from that string with this:

```
        String str = "text java.awt.Color[r=128,g=128,b=128]text 1234";
        String[] temp = str.split("[,]?[r,g,b][=]|[]]");
        String[] colorValues = new String[3];
        int index = 0;
        for (String string : temp) {
            try {
                Integer.parseInt(string);
                colorValues[index] = string;
                index++;
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(colorValues)); //to verify the output
```

The above example extract the values in an array of Strings, if you want in an array of ints:

```
        String str = "text java.awt.Color[r=128,g=128,b=128]text 1234";
        String[] temp = str.split("[,]?[r,g,b][=]|[]]");
        int[] colorValues = new int[3];
        int index = 0;
        for (String string : temp) {
            try {
                colorValues[index] = Integer.parseInt(string);
                index++;
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(colorValues)); //to verify the output
```

Comment: And say for example I have a string with multiple of these `java.awt.Color[[r=128,g=128,b=128]`. How would I get each one out separately then?

Comment: @toadless Is almost the same, just use `ArrayList` instead, to add all the values there and then split by 3 the elements inside.

Answer (score 0):

As said before, you will need to parse the text. This will allow you to return the RGB values from inside the string. I would try something like this.

```java
private static int[] getColourVals(String s){
  int[] vals = new int[3];
  String[] annotatedVals = s.split("\\[|\\]")[1].split(","); // Split the string on either [ or ] and then split the middle element by ,
  for(int i = 0; i < annotatedVals.length; i++){
    vals[i] = Integer.parseInt(annotatedVals[i].split("=")[1]); // Split by the = and only get the value
  }
  return vals;
}
```